# Form isn't showing when app is started in Release mode, when in Debug it is showing

Tags: c#

I have a form, and when I run app in Visual Studio in Release mode it isn't showing, when I run it in Debug mode it is showing. How can I check what is causing this ? I add try catch but no error occurs.

```
IAddPaymentView view = new AddPaymentForm();

AddPaymentPresenter addPaymentPresenter = new AddPaymentPresenter(view, this.tabPageView.SelectedIdPlayer);
```

Thanks

Comment: When you debug it.. what is the Solutions Configuration setup as Debug.. or Release.. also are you porting over the correct code..? it resides in different folders if you are not aware of that Debug / Release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you debug it.. what is the Solutions Configuration setup as Debug.. or Release.. also are you porting over the correct code..? it resides in different folders if you are not aware of that Debug / Release .. is there an option as well to make that form the startup Project

Comment: Yes AddPaymentPresenter is in another folder then from which it is created and called

Comment: Can you check on the project and see if it allows for a startup form or project.. this is what it sounds like to me..can't really tell much from the 2 lines of code you posted

Comment: I forgot write, that I added obsfuscator if /I "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" Eazfuscator.NET.exe "$(TargetPath)" --msbuild-project-path "$(ProjectPath)" --msbuild-project-configuration "$(ConfigurationName)" --msbuild-project-platform "$(PlatformName)" --msbuild-solution-path "$(SolutionPath)" -n --newline-flush -v 3.2, maybe this is the reason ?

Comment: But this form isn't form of application. My application start normally. But when it start in one of the windows I have button Add payments. When I click into this button form AddPaymentsForm should be shown, but it isn't (code above)

Comment: Yes I am already sure, tha reason of this problem is Eazfuscator, how to resolve it ?